# pushing a branch to a new repository on github

Tags: git, github

I did git clone on some open source blogging software, and then created a branch on my local machine called `myblog`. Therefore, when I went to push to github, I wasn't able to do

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/Me/myrepository.git
```

because the origin already existed, which I cloned from.

therefore, I did

```
git remote add myblog  https://github.com/Me/myrepository.git
```

I did 'myblog' because it's the name of my branch, maybe that wasn't necessary. To push the instructions I had said that to push you do

```
 git push origin master
```

but since I wasn't pushing to origin, and I wasn't pushing a master, I did

```
   git push myrepository myblog
```

but it said 'myrepository' did not appear to be a git repository. Then I did

```
git push myblog myblog
```

the first 'myblog' was for the repository, the second for my branch. This push worked. The actual app is on my github account.  I can see it. However, when I tried to do a git clone on it (i.e. the app that I pushed), it copied
this (what you see in the image) into my directory on my machine (not the blogging app)

[image]

I can't clone the blogging software in my github repository back on my machine.
It might also be important to know that, as I was trying to figure things out, I also did

```
git push -u myblog
```

and it said

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

My question:  Why is it copying that (what you see in the image) into my directory on my computer when the app is actually on my github account. And, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the repository on github, it created a `master` branch with a README inside. When you pushed the `myblog` branch, you created a `myblog` branch on the server, leaving the `master` branch alone (still just a README).

It looks like you've since changed your local `master` branch to no longer be directly related to the remove `master` branch (hence the non-fast-forward message).  If you want to forget the old `master` content, you can force git to overwrite the server's version with `git push -f`.

When you `push` without specifying a branch, the default (to be changed in git 2.0) is to push all matching branches.  So, both `myblog` and `master` will be pushed (assuming they're both present in the local and remote repos). If you just want to push `myblog` and not worry about any conflict with `master`, you can specify the name, i.e. `git push myblog myblog`.

Or, you can switch your default push behavior to `simple` (the new default in git 2.0), which will just push the current branch (assuming that the names match between local and remote).  Do this with `git config push.default simple`.